# IP address in email header?

Tags: email, ip

I sent an email through my normal internet provider.

Afterwards, I set up an account so I’d have VPN to hide/randomize my IP address.

If someone traces the original email (before I got vpn to change my IP address) will that yahoo email I sent, have my original IP address?

I didn’t get VPN yet, so now I’m wondering if they’ll see my IP address.

[It was through YAHOO email, using a mobile phone.]

Comment: Yes, the recipient and the MTAs in the chain will see your IP address.

Comment: I'm not clear on your question. Are you asking about affecting a past email if you take future actions? Also are you using a POP/IMAP client or are you using Web based email?

Comment: The VPN is not a factor because you had not set one up yet. You can safely remove that from all consideration because it's not relevant to what you've asked.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/237525/ip-address-leaked-in-email-header

Comment: If sending the email from an app from your phone, or from a web browser, your IP is not sent at all. You can test this by sending an email to yourself and reading the email header or copying the header into a [header analyser](https://mxtoolbox.com/EmailHeaders.aspx) to check what IPs are entered in the email chain to the recipient.

Comment: Thank you @schroeder. I did send emails to myself (using NO vpn). Plus I did replies to myself. The last numbers of the IP addresses changed each time, but I realized it was Yahoo IP address, which they obviously have several IP addresses.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score -1):

When a mail transport agent (a mail server) receives an email, it's required to add a `Received` header indicating from where it received the data.  This customarily contains information about the hostname or IP of the server, the date and time of receipt, the protocol used (including whether it was authenticated), and potentially other information.  In addition, it may include information about the account used to send the mail, which is useful for dealing with abuse problems.

The information that's recorded is what the mail server recorded when the mail was received.  If you sent the mail from a machine without using the VPN, then the public IP address will be recorded as part of the email, regardless of whether you use a VPN or otherwise change your IP address later.  If you were using a VPN when the mail was sent and you properly configured it, then the VPN's IP address will be used.

If you used a webmail client, the webmail client, as a tool that processes email, will also probably insert a `Received` header before forwarding it onto the mail server, and it will usually insert the IP address it saw as well.  The same policy applies from the paragraph above, just substitute "webmail interface" with "mail server."

Do note that if you sent a mail to your normal ISP, regardless of whether you used a VPN, they will probably record the fact that you authenticated to send the mail, either in the email, or in their logs.  All reputable providers require some sort of authentication (or other sender verification, such as an IP check) before sending mail destined for other domains, because otherwise spammers would abuse those servers.  Thus, it's not possible to send an anonymous email directly through your ISP's mail server unless you use a service such as a remailer.

Comment: "the webmail client ... will also probably insert a Received header before forwarding" --- this is very easy to test. I tried a few email clients on mobile devices and webmail using a browser and none entered my IP, the starting IP was the email server/email company. This is why I was asking the OP how it was sent. While this answer is true in a specific context, it is not true in all. And in the case of sending email through the Yahoo mail app on a phone, this answers appears not to apply.